# How should I compare each element values in two lists?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tdd

In my unit test method,

I am having two list. One is the **expectedValueList** and other is **actualvalueList**.

```
expectedValueList={a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4}

actualvalueList={d=4,b=2,c=3,a=1}
```

I am comparing only one element by doing this

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedValueList.Select(x => x.a).ToList() ,actualvalueList.Select(x => x.a).ToList())
```

how to compare remaining elements ?

Comment: It's hard to tell what the type is here. Are you suggesting these are actually two lists each with a single entry, or are there four entries each of which is effectively a key/value pair? Actual code would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: it is list not key value pair .all type are integer

Comment: So you have just got a single value? Why have you listed the fields in a different order in the two lists? That confuses things significantly. Again, *actual code* showing the list types would make this much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) if they are already in order directly

```
expectedValueList.SequenceEqual(actualvalueList);
```

if they are not in order than you can apply ordering as well before using sequence equal like

```
expectedValueList.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(actualvalueList.OrderBy(y => y));
```

Example

```
List<int> l1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
List<int> l2 = new List<int> { 3, 1, 2, 4 };

if (l1.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(l2.OrderBy(y => y)))
{
     Console.WriteLine("List are equal"); // will write this
}

if (l1.SequenceEqual(l2))
{
     Console.WriteLine("List are equal"); 
}
else
{    
     Console.WriteLine("List are not equal"); // will write this    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am expecting its a `List<int>` and not key-value pairs as you mentioned in comments. try something like this:

```
Assert.AreEqual(actualvalueList.Count(), expectedValueList.Count());
for(int i=0;i<actualvalueList.Count();i++)
{
   Assert.AreEqual(actualvalueList[i], expectedValueList[i]);
}
```

or

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedValueList, actualvalueList);
```

### Edit

if you don't want to compare one value, then remove from Lists:

```
actualvalueList.Remove(actualvalueList.Select(x => x.d).FirstOrDefault())
```

Comment: @Ahmed:quick reply good,if i don't want to compare type "d" from lists.what could be better approach

Comment: This is basically what CollectionAssert already does, so I don't think it's actually adding anything.

Comment: if any one list is different from other list ,in that case getting error(i.e sequence doesn't match).in that what to do?

Comment: @JonSkeet OP is using CollectionAssert but he is actually only comparing first element by selecting it with LINQ

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed: Yes, but my point is that the code you posted provides no benefit over just calling `CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedValueList, actualValueList)`. Additionally, it doesn't sound like this *is* a `List<int>` to start with, or `x.a` wouldn't exist, would it?

Answer (score 0):

Just create the function that returns needed fields

```
Func<TItem, object> itemSelector = (item) => new { A = item.a };
```

and use SequenceEqual for comparison

```
expectedValueList.Select(itemSelector).SequenceEqual(actualvalueList.Select(itemSelector )
```