# how to exclude the property and then compare the list

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, tdd

In my unit test method is created which has two list of objects,

i.e One is the `expectedValueList` and other is `actualvalueList`.

```
expectedValueList={a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4}

actualvalueList={d=4,b=2,c=3,a=1}
```

i am comparing by

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedValueList, actualvalueList);
```

I need to exclude the `"c" property` from both the list and then i want compare the two list equal or not?

Comment: What Collection is `expectedValueList` and `actualvalueList`?

Comment: It is of System.Collection IList

Comment: `IList<int>`? How do you identify `"c"`?

Comment: is this is same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395555/how-should-i-compare-each-element-values-in-two-lists

Comment: you have already asked this question in the morning. Don't post duplicate.

Comment: @pratapk yes it is, and instead of clarifying it there he asked again

Comment: @kumar pls try to modify the first question and pls don't post another question .......

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, please consider to  accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that both lists are `List<CustomType>` where `CustomType` has two properties. Now you need a way to compare both lists but ignore one value.

If the order matters i would use [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx):

```
var expectedWithoutC = expectedValueList.Where(t => t.Name != "c");
var actualWithoutC = actualvalueList.Where(t => t.Name != "c");
bool bothEqual = expectedWithoutC.SequenceEqual(actualWithoutC);
```

Note that you need to override `Equals` (and `GetHashCode`) if my presumption was correct. Otherwise `SequenceEqual` will just compare for reference equality.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `expectedValueList` is a `Dictionary<string, int>`.

```
var expectedValueList = new SortedDictionary<string, int> { { "a", 1 }, { "b", 2 }, { "c", 3 }, { "d", 4 } };
expectedValueList.Remove("c");

var actualValueList = new SortedDictionary<string, int> { { "d", 4 }, { "b", 2 }, { "c", 3 }, { "a", 1 } };
actualValueList.Remove("c");

// Will return false if the order is different.
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedValueList, actualvalueList);
```

Comment: :it is of System.Collection IList

Comment: I think the dv is harsh given what information Sam Leach had to work on. (counter voted)